# Why chaining matters (Python & SQLite3)?

Tags: python, sqlite

Why does

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("...
return cursor.fetchall()
```

return the expected non-empty result whereas

```
connection.cursor().execute("...
return connection.cursor().fetchall()
```

returns an empty list the SQLite3-command being identical in both cases?

EDIT 2014-02-19: Added the last "...fetchall()"-line to code samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `sqlite3` library, the `cursor.execute()` call always returns the cursor object again. Both your statements are identical here:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> conn.cursor().execute('SELECT DATE()')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1083d89d0>
>>> cursor = conn.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute('SELECT DATE()')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1083d8960>
```

However, if you didn't store a reference to the cursor returned from the 'chained' call, you won't have access to the result set anymore, a new cursor object from `connection.cursor()` won't list those results as it'll be a different cursor object:

```
>>> conn.cursor().execute('SELECT DATE()')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1083d8a40>
>>> list(conn.cursor())
[]
>>> cursor = conn.cursor().execute('SELECT DATE()')
>>> list(cursor)
[(u'2014-02-18',)]
```

That has nothing to do with chaining and everything with the purpose of cursors: to provide distinct views on the database, each with their own independent state.

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)